# VMWare - How do i configure Host Only Network with a custom Gateway?

Tags: vmware, configure, dhcp

I'll make this quick.

I have created a virtual network by setting several VMs to use HostOnly VMnet1 as their network adapter.
I then added a pfsense virtual machine firewall into that same network and configured it to allow traffic to the internet but block to/from my real home network.
That way - my virtual network can connect to the internet even though it is in host only mode.

The thing is, I need to manually set the DNS and Gateway of each machine in VMNet1 to the VM firewall to allow them to communicate since all communications must flow through it.

I was trying to figure out if I can do this automatically. When I go into Virtual Network settings in VMWare Workstation 16, the only options I can set are the subnet and available IP Scope. There is no option for default gateway or DNS here. Can this be done?

Answer (score -1):

Do you have the ability to run a DHCP server on the PFSense firewall which is connected to the VMNetwork?  If so, either Windows and Linux VMs that have their NICs set to DHCP, would get the IP, DNS and GW from the DHCP.